# Unable to deploy war file in tomcat9

Tags: tomcat

when i'm trying to deploy war file in tomcat9 i'm getting following message "FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: Cannot find operation isServiced" please help

Comment: Coincidentially, I'm getting the same issue today. Found a solution?

Comment: No.I installed Xampp which has tomcat 7.It has no issues as of now

Comment: This is bug in 8.5.13 and M19. You need change version http://stackoverflow.com/a/43232552/4629628

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a recent bug that now has a fix applied for the next release:

https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@tomcat.apache.org/msg116634.html

Comment: I reverted to apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18 and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, and you can find below the exception from my tomcat manager log file:

```
    04-Apr-2017 19:19:24.126 SEVERE [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-4] org.apache.cata$
 javax.management.MBeanException: Cannot find operation isServiced04-Apr-2017 1$
 javax.management.MBeanException: Cannot find operation isServiced
```