# Deploying in tomcat with exception: Cannot find operation isServiced

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, war, tomcat-manager

I installed Tomcat and Tomcat Manager on a remote server as per the instructions on [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

After adding it I successfully accessed the manager on `http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/manager/html`

Then I used the war file upload option to try to deploy the war file on it but it gives the following exception.

`FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: Cannot find operation isServiced`

[Documentation on `isServiced`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/manager/ManagerServlet.html#isServiced(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just looked this up. Broken in Tomcat versions M19 and 8.5.13. Fixed in upcoming versions M20 and in 8.5.14. http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60949. So you can roll back to M18 or 8.5.12 for now.

Comment: Tomcat 8.5.14 has since been released. I wasted valuable hours on this issue. I was using Tomcat 8.5.13. See http://tomcat.apache.org

Answer (score 4):

Sachi, I had the same issue, I was working with Tomcat 9 M19 and just went back to Tomcat 9 M18 and everything worked well again.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Dan! You should post this as an answer for visibility and correctness.

Comment: @DanHalbert so the given versions are still not available right? Which means that the solution would be to step down in the version?

Comment: Right, to M18 or 8.5.12.

Comment: Tomcat 8.5.14 has since been released. I wasted valuable hours on this issue. I was using Tomcat 8.5.13. See http://tomcat.apache.org

Answer (score 1):

I was using Netbeans to develop my code when I landed with the same error. I was using Tomcat 9.0.0.M19. I followed the suggestion provided by Dan and Jon above and changed my server path in Netbeans to point to the previous version of Tomcat i.e. 9.0.0.M18 and things started working.

You can download the previous version from http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M18/bin/

For MAC I downloaded http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M18/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18.tar.gz

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused due to tomcat version incompatibility.
Please change tomcat version and your are good to go .