# Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.(ubuntu16.04+intellij2016.3.4+tomcat8.5.13)

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

I delveloped a project in springmvc and maven by intellij.

When the project is running in windows 10 and tomcat8.5.13,it works well.But when it runs in ubuntu16.04, there are some erros:

> Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

I am sure that my code is correct because I can run it in windows10 or mac os.And I used the same version of tomcat in these os——v8.5.13.

I have read many answers in the sof,but no one can solve my problem.

And the most strange thing is:though there are some errors when I run the tomcat in my intellij, I can find my web in http://localhost:8080 correctly.

Comment: Show the errors from the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had the same problem on MacOS X and the log files are clear without any error. After changing tomcat version back to 8.5.12 all is ok. Seems like they broke something in 8.5.13 and 9.0.0.M19 versions. 
Similar problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43205092/deploying-in-tomcat-with-exception-cannot-find-operation-isserviced)

Older versions of tomcat can be downloaded from [here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.12/bin/)

Comment: I changed the version of tomcat to 8.5.12 and it really works!!! Thank you very much!